# How to turn off System : Decoration Calculation in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse whenever I try to build a project or refresh workspace, system decoration calculation process is always occuring in progress view? This disrupts building project process. How to stop it?

Answer (score 4):

Go to Preference

General -> Appearance -> Label Decorations.

Select the decorators you want to turn off.

Comment: I tried but it did not work. As it appears in progress view so I can kill the process as well, but what is the permanent solution for this?